# I am having a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong since the auto grader for my class says the output is incorrect

Tags: python, eof

First image is my code and the second is my output and the output  that it expects.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkhWn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPaeN.png)

It asks for me to input 5 different sets of numbers which is why I have multiple in the program.
the sets are (3,1,4) (1,1,0) (21,12,5) (,0,0,0) and (23,99,40)

Im trying to figure out why my output is showing 314 at the beginning and the 1 at the end, mainly the highlighted part of my output.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Don't post images of code.  Post the actual code, as a [mre].  People can't copy/paste from the images you posted.